# Updating sprite Rect each frame

Tags: c++, sprites, marmalade

I have made a struct which sets 4 variables that define a rect

```
void setDestSize(int width, int height)
        {
           Width = width;
           Height = height;
        }
        void setSrcRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
           SrcX = x;
           SrcY = y; 
           SrcWidth = width;
           SrcHeight = height;
        }
```

and I have a class that uses CSprite and it draws an Image. In my Render function it has
if (Visible)
    {
        Transform.SetIdentity();

```
    // Build transform
    Transform.SetRot(Angle);
    Transform.ScaleRot(Scale);
    Transform.SetTrans(Position);
    Iw2DSetTransformMatrix(Transform);
    Iw2DSetColour(Colour);
    // Render image
    if (ShipBullet != 0)
        Iw2DDrawImage(ShipBullet, CIwFVec2(Position.x, Position.y));

    boundingRect.srcX = Position.x;
    boundingRect.SrcY = Position.y;

    Iw2DSetColour(0xff0000ff); // Set red
    Iw2DDrawRect(CIwFVec2(boundingRect.srcX, boundingRect.SrcY),
        CIwFVec2(boundingRect.Width, boundingRect.Height));
```

When I draw that rect, It's drawn somewhere else, and its not bounded on the sprite..

Comment: you need to pass the position parameter in your draw function

Comment: pass it where ? in which function?

Comment: in the draw function ? Iw2DDrawImage(Image, CIwSVec2(x, y)); isn't the second parameter supposed to be the position of image you want to draw ?

Comment: yes, correct. I will edit my code, to the new one. Still the bounding rect is drawn to other places, not bounding the sprite.

Comment: im not exactly sure what you are doing and how much experience you have doing this, but usually draw functions are something like draw(image,position,source) where position is the draw position(x,y), and source is the rectangle which describes which part of the image you want to draw for example rect(x',y',width,height), i don't know the variables of the functions you are calling, but it shoudn't be too hard to figure it out

Comment: I don't have a src rect in my api. it just draws an image with a position. so I made a bounding rect on my own, and I want to use it for collision detection

Comment: Then all you need is to use a draw(image,position) function

Comment: yes but what about the bounding rect ? how would I update its srcx, srxy

Comment: you need to explain better what you are trying to do. you are supposed to update the X and Y variables (depending on your game logic) and draw your image to the (X,Y) position, are you trying to do something different ?